# Turning vector of shared_ptr into vector of shared_ptr to const

Tags: c++, vector, undefined-behavior, reinterpret-cast, const-correctness

Let

```
class A
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> v_;
};
```

Now I'd like to add access to `v_` using two public member functions

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> const & v() { return v_; }
```

and

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int const> const & v() const { TODO }
```

I cannot replace `TODO` with `return v_;` though.

One option would be to not return a reference but a copy.  Apart from the obvious performance penalty, this would also make the interface somewhat less desirable.

Another option is to make `TODO` equal to `return reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int const>> const &>(v_);`

My question is, is this undefined behavior?  Or, alternatively, is there a better option, preferably without using `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why do you have a pointer to an `int` (or `const int`)? If you have a pointer to an "array" wouldn't a vector make more sense?

Comment: You can return an iterator

Comment: The `int` was merely an example, in the actual code it's a big class.

Comment: Regarding the "performance penalty" have you *measured* it? Modern compilers are pretty good at optimizing such situations, especially when it can employ move semantics.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by allowing direct access to `v_`? I'm asking because I believe that will dictate what's the best answer

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm actually not concerned about the performance.  I would be fine with returning a copy.  But then I'd better also return a copy in the non-const case to have a uniform interface.  This in turn makes it impossible to return a `&`, not a `const &` in the non-const case.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'd like to, for example, allow range-based loops over `v_`.  In my actual code, I'd prefer to return a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> &` with non-const `v()` so that an outside user can even change `v_`.

Comment: You shouldn't be returning a vector at all if the caller doesn't need the vector interface. You can probably do what you want by defining your own proxy type that offers `begin`, `end` and `operator[]`. For the `const` case I don't think you'll avoid returning a copy of the `shared_ptr` as it doesn't seem like you can safely `reinterpret_cast` it to `shared_ptr<const T>` without relying on specific implementations. But at least you won't have to preemptively copy the whole vector.

Answer (score 6):

A way to avoid copying the container is to provide transform iterators that transform the element on dereference:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

class A
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> > v_;

    struct Transform
    {
        template<class T>
        std::shared_ptr<T const> operator()(std::shared_ptr<T> const& p) const {
            return p;
        }
    };

public:

    A() : v_{std::make_shared<int>(1), std::make_shared<int>(2)} {}

    using Iterator = boost::transform_iterator<Transform, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> >::const_iterator>;

    Iterator begin() const { return Iterator{v_.begin()}; }
    Iterator end() const { return Iterator{v_.end()}; }

};

int main() {
    A a;
    // Range access.
    for(auto const& x : a)
        std::cout << *x << '\n';
    // Indexed access.
    auto iterator_to_second_element = a.begin() + 1;
    std::cout << **iterator_to_second_element << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Using `boost::transform_iterator` is an elegant way to do the "proxy approach".  Thank you for the good suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

Putting aside the discussion of whether or not you should return a reference to a member...

`std::vector` already propagates its own `const` qualifier to the references, pointee's and iterators it returns. The only hurdle is making it propagate further to the pointee type of the `std::shared_ptr`. You can use a class like [`std::experimental::propagate_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) (that will hopefully be standardized) to facilitate that. It will do as its name implies, for any pointer or pointer-like object it wraps.

```
class A
{
    using ptr_type = std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<int>>;
    std::vector<ptr_type> v_;
};
```

Thus `TODO` can become `return v_;`, and any access to the pointees (like in the range-based for you wish to support) will preserve const-ness.

Only caveat is that it's a moveable only type, so copying out an element of the vector will require a bit more work (for instance, by calling [`std::experimental::get_underlying`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const/get_underlying)) with the element type of the vector itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I actually tried using `propagate_const` first.  However, the caveat you mention seems rather strong to me.  There is a member function `get()` in `propagate_const` that does nicely what I'd like, but only for raw pointers.  There is no `get_underlying()` member function that returns the actual pointer-like type held in a const-correct way.  But using the non-member `get_underlying()` undermines the whole const-correctness.

Comment: @Xoph I don't follow. Member vs non-member doesn't matter here. You would either have an implicit `const propagate_const<T> *` (`this`) or an explicit `const propagate_const<T> &` (parameter), with the same const semantics

Comment: @Caleth What I'm trying to say is: if you have a `const propagate_cast<shared_ptr<T>>`, getting a `shared_ptr<T const>` from it is harder than I'd like it to be and involves breaking const-correctness by requiring you to use `get_underlying()` to get a `shared_ptr<T>` and then converting it into a `shared_ptr<T const>` from what I can tell.

Comment: @Xoph Yes, because `shared_ptr<T>` is a different type to `shared_ptr<const T>` (although there is a converting constructor which maintains the shared-ness)

Comment: @Xoph [`const`] `propagate_const<shared_ptr<T>>` will do what you want except for being non-copyable. If you can define the API yourself, and don't need copies, there is no reason to use `shared_ptr<const T>`. So this a big question here: Do you need copies? Then again, if you *don't* need copies, what is the point of using `shared_ptr` other than more concise code?

Comment: @ArneVogel I do need copies. :)